# Active Storage multiple attachments per record in a separate way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've looked in the official guides but can't resolve this.

I have a model `campaign` which needs to have multiple image attachments that are different between them such as `campaignlogo`, `campaigndesign`, `campaignextra`.

I'm using active storage to make this possible, but don't know how to approach it.

**¿Can I use multiple `has_one_attached` in the campaign model?**

```
  has_one_attached :campaignextra
  has_one_attached :campaigndesign
  has_one_attached :campaignlogo
```

I see there is an option `has_many_attached`, but works only for a same attachment type (ex. images). Is it possible to use this method for this? How would it work in the form view if i want to have multiple file uploads for each one of them?

Thanks a lot

Comment: has_one_attached doesn't work? why?

Comment: you really want to do it the way that you are doing it. how else would you tell apart the `campaignextra` from the `campaigndesign` or the `campaignlogo ` if they are all part of the same attachment set?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to the similar kind of problem. Have you figured out any solution?